# $\Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$ is path connected when $n>1$

Tags: general-topology

Prove $\Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$ is path connected when $n>1$

Is $f(t)=(1-t)x+ty$ a suitable function?

Comment: Let $n=2$ and $x = (-1,0), y = (1,0)$

Comment: No. That function is a line segment between $x$ and $y$. However, that line segment may cut $0$, for example when $x=-y$

Comment: I don't think there's a very simple formula for a path from one arbitrary point to another. However, you can stitch your path together with a rotation to make it work nicely, albeit in two parts, or you can use your formula _except_ when the origin is between your two points, and use something else for those special cases.

Comment: @Arthur Is there a way to prove path connectedness without finding a formula?

Comment: Of course. You could describe a path using words instead (which I personally think would look better in this case). There are also a few different algebraic invariants you could compute that imply connectedness, specifically homology and homotopy groups (and others, I'm sure).

Answer (score 3):

If the segment from $x$ to $y$ doesn't contain $0$, that path works.

Otherwise, you can use the fact that the line containing $x$ and $y$ is not the whole $\mathbb{R}^n$, so there is a point $z$ outside it. Three non aligned points lie on a circle (so the path is even differentiable).

Comment: "three non aligned points lie on a circle" is that really obvious even if $n > 3$?

Comment: @user159517 Three nonaligned points determine a plane (in this case even a two-dimensional subspace, because we're assuming that $0$ belongs to the line through two of the points).

Answer (score 1):

Given two points $x,y\in \mathbf{R}^n$, assume they are at distances $r$ and $R$ from the origin respectively. Assume $r\leq R$. Now consider vectors $ax$ with $a\in [1, R/r]$. This is a path from $x$ to $x'$, with $x'$ at the same distance as $y$ from  the origin.

Now draw a circle with centre at origin and radius $R$ passing through $x'$ and $y$. Thus there is a path consisting of a straight line segment and then circular arc joins the given two points. Most of the times straight line path is available.